# runas domain access?

Tags: windows-7, script, batch-file, domain, runas

I want to execute a file on a share but I need to use a domain account to access it. I've tried `runas /user:domain\user \\someshare\foo.exe`. It prompts for the domain account's password, which I enter, but then I get "RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run... 2: The system cannot find the file specified." Is this possible with runas? Is there another way to accomplish this from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network connections are per-session and aren't carried over by `runas`.

You need to `runas /u:domain\user cmd` first.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to use the admin account to access the file, have you tried using the `/netonly` switch?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to map the drive. Use [NET USE](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) to do this and then use `runas` to the drive letter you assign, like

```
net use z: \\someshare
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Steven Try this then, Browse to the program and Shift Right Click on the program and click Run as different user then enter your credentials.

Comment: I can't browse to the program as the current user because the current user is not a domain account and therefore does not have access to it.